# events on the where ignore items that matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this in my controller

```
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id))
```

Basically at the moment it i have this in an each statement in my view. However, at the moment its showing up like this:

```
alex,
Sam,
Sam,
billy,
billy
```

What im wanting it to return like is this

```
alex,
sam,
billy
```

I've tried using `.distinct` and `.unique` on the end to no prevail

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
@events = Event.where(id: popular.map(&:impressionable_id).uniq)
```

Comment: Didnt work, It passed back the ids as unique, which they are, but he event names are the same :(

Comment: Could you pls elaborate your question? What do you wanna exactly do and how your db schema looks like?